# No parameterless constructor defined for this object in mvc5

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2013

I am working in mvc5. In visual studio 2013 the solution is working fine but when i tried to deploy it in IIS an error " No parameterless constructor defined for this project in mvc5" on the following line

```
@Html.Action("Login", "User", new { Area = "User" })
```

but still the solution running successfully!!

any body there to help me on this.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My viewmodel was previously like as follows

```
namespace Delivros.UI.Areas.User.ViewModel
{
public class UserRegistrationModel 
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Required", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Required", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Login", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "IncorrectMail")]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "UserRegistrationPassword", ResourceType = typeof(Delivros.UI.Resources))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "PasswordMatch", ResourceType = typeof(Delivros.UI.Resources))]
    [Compare("Password",ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "PasswordMatch")]

    public string ReEnterPassword { get; set; }

    public bool IsSchoolAdmin { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }
    public SchoolUser SchoolUser { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SchoolInternalStructure> SchoolInternalStructre { get; set; }
    public bool IsConfirmedByAdmin { get; set; }
    public Gender GenderType { get; set; }
    public UserRole RoleType { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<UserRoleDefinitionInternal> UserRoleDefinitionInternal { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}}
```

and I changed it as follows by adding a parameter less constructor inside that

```
namespace Delivros.UI.Areas.User.ViewModel
{
public class UserRegistrationModel 
{
    public UserRegistrationModel()
         { 
         }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Required", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Required", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Login", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "IncorrectMail")]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "UserRegistrationPassword", ResourceType = typeof(Delivros.UI.Resources))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "PasswordMatch", ResourceType = typeof(Delivros.UI.Resources))]
    [Compare("Password",ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "PasswordMatch")]

    public string ReEnterPassword { get; set; }

    public bool IsSchoolAdmin { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }
    public SchoolUser SchoolUser { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SchoolInternalStructure> SchoolInternalStructre { get; set; }
    public bool IsConfirmedByAdmin { get; set; }
    public Gender GenderType { get; set; }
    public UserRole RoleType { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<UserRoleDefinitionInternal> UserRoleDefinitionInternal { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```